# How to destroy a specific object when clicked on by mouse?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently making a sandbox game and it is able to create a object through left click. But, I am struggling to destroy a specific object when it is right clicked. I've looked on previous questions here, but they don't exactly answer my question.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ControlObjects : MonoBehaviour
{

    Vector3 mousePosition, targetPosition;

    //To Instantiate TargetObject at mouse position
    public Transform targetObject;
    public GameObject Prefab;

    float distance = 10f;

    Ray ray;
    RaycastHit hit;

    //public int item_num = 1;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = targetPosition;


        //To get the current mouse position
        mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;

        //Convert the mousePosition according to World position
        targetPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(mousePosition.x, mousePosition.y, distance));

        //Set the position of targetObject
        targetObject.position = targetPosition;

        //Debug.Log(mousePosition+"   "+targetPosition);


        //If Left Button is clicked
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            //create the instance of targetObject and place it at given position.
            Instantiate(targetObject, targetObject.transform.position, targetObject.transform.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to "pick" the object and then call `Destroy` on it. Usually picking is done via raycasting

Comment: @UnholySheep the problem is that I'm slightly new to Unity and do not know how to do that.

Comment: The official page has lots of tutorials, e.g.: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/raycasting (and the documentation is also pretty good)

Comment: @UnholySheep I'll have a look

Answer (score 0):

Implement what you need, but this is the base.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float distance = 10;
    private float offset = -4;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse1))
        {
            GameObject go = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);

            go.transform.position = new Vector3
            {
                x = offset += 1.5f,
                y = 0,
                z = 0
            };
        }

        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit, distance))
            {
                Destroy(hit.transform.gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [IPointerClickHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html). Attach this script to the objects you want to be able to click on

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class DestroyOnRightClick : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler 
{
    public void OnPointerClick (PointerEventData eventData) 
    {
        if (eventData.button == PointerEventData.InputButton.Right) 
        {
             Debug.Log ("Right Mouse Button Clicked on: " + name);
             Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**

> Ensure an `EventSystem` exists in the Scene to allow click detection. For click detection on **non-UI** GameObjects, ensure a [PhysicsRaycaster](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.PhysicsRaycaster.html) is attached to the `Camera`.